# How to merge list of words (remove duplicates)?

Tags: notepad++

I am editing a long list of unique words (one word per line) in one text file.

I used Notepad++ and TextFXTools to merge list of words, and worked OK. I would add new words at the bottom of the list and used FXTools to remove duplicates.
It worked until the list became big, a couple of million words. Notepad++ frequently crashes with lists this big.

I need a way to add new list of words to one big list, delete duplicates and keep only unique words. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool from a HTML5 browser:
http://textmechanic.com/Big-File-Tool-Remove-Duplicate-Lines.html

Comment: Thanks, would like to avoid online tools, file is pretty large, and because of privacy concerns. I need windows desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Excel and go to A1 Cell, enter something as a heading
2. Paste your records on A2, A3, A4..... Cell
3. Choose A1 Cell and go to `Data` -> `Advance` -> Click `OK` when a prompt come up
4. Click `Unique Data Only` and Click `OK`
5. Now the list should be no duplicate data